# SQL signup feature $_POST method being annoying

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Ok, this is just for a school project so it doesn't need incredible security so i just need help with this signup feature for an sql database:

```
<h1>Signup:</h1><br><form method="post">Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="cpassword"><br><input type="submit"></form>
            <?php
                $user = $_POST['username'];
                $pass = crypt($_POST['password'], '$1a');
                $cpass = crypt($_POST['cpassword'], '$1a');
                if($pass == $cpass) {
                    $query = "INSERT INTO users (uName, pWord) VALUES ('$user', '$pass')";
                }
                  else
                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Password is different');</script>";
            ?>
```

The problem i actually have is i am doing pretty much the same thing with the login and the $_POST method in there is stopping me from being able to do it here, how do i refer to a specific $_POST method?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to actually execute the query. You're just assigning a string to a variable.

Comment: There is actually another problem, the error it was throwing at me is that it doesn't accept cpassword in the first line, could you be so kind as to tell me what I did wrong again?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: cpassword in C:\xampp\htdocs\rent\index.php on line 50    (the $_cpass)

Comment: You probably haven't typed a value into the cpassword field. Try doing print_r($_POST); in your script to check which fields have been entered. You should catch the field not being populated, so you should validate it first. If you don't care about validating the passwords just use _$cpass = crypt((array_key_exists('cpassword', $_POST) ? $_POST['cpassword'] : '', '$1a');_